# Why is my table heading pushing the table rows out of place?

Tags: html, html-table

Without a heading, my table looks fine and normal. I tried adding a table heading and it pushed everything out of place. Could anyone tell me how to avoid this?

Relevant code:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="white">
<th width="80%"> Let's talk about the wall </th>
<tr>
<td width="6%" align="center" bgcolor="white"><font face="arial"><strong></strong></font></td>
<td width="75%" align="center" bgcolor="white"><font face="arial"><strong></strong></font></td>
<td width="19%" align="center" bgcolor="white"><font face="arial"><strong></strong></font></td>
</tr>
```

And then:

```
<tr>
<td bgcolor="white"><font face="arial"></font></td>
<td bgcolor="white"><a href="view_topic.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"><font face="arial"><? echo $rows['topic']; ?></a><BR></font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="white"><font face="arial"></font></td>
</tr>
```

[image: Obviously mutated table]

To be clear, the text you see such as 'test,' 'slaaa,' etc. - I want that to be aligned much farther to the left of where it sits, which is how it sits when I have the table without a heading.

Comment: Your heading is one cell, but in the rest of your table, each row has three cells. If you want the heading to cover all three columns, look into the colspan attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `tr` wrapping the `th`, and a `colspan`

```css
th {
  background: #ccc;
}

td {
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="white">
<tr>
  <th colspan="3"> Let's talk about the wall</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="6%" align="center" bgcolor="white">
    <strong>some text</strong>
  </td>
  <td width="75%" align="center" bgcolor="white">
    <strong>Column 2</strong>
  </td>
  <td width="19%" align="center" bgcolor="white">
    <strong>Column 3</strong>
  </td>
</tr>
```